# Splitting a string of numbers with different digit sizes in Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, split

I'm trying to figure out if there's a way to split a string that contains numbers with different digit sizes without having to use if/else statements. Is there an outright method for doing so. Here is an example string:

```
"123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930"
```

So that it would be split into an array containing 1-9 and 10-30 without having to first split the array into single digits, separate it, find the 9, and iterate through combining every 2 elements after the 9.

Here is the current way I would go about doing this to clarify:

```
single_digits, double_digits = [], []
string = "123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930".split('')

single_digits << string.slice!(0,9)
single_digits.map! {|e| e.to_i}
string.each_slice(2) {|num| double_digits << num.join.to_i}
```

This would give me:

```
single_digits = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
double_digits = [10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]
```

Comment: How is it that you know that the first instance of "10" should mean ten?  More generally, how do you know where to split?

Comment: If you already know that the numbers are in order starting with 1, then forget the string and do: [1..30].each {|n| arry[]=n.to_s}

Comment: That's what the question is. If you use #split('').map {|e| e.to_i} it will create an array of all single digits. You can then run #slice(0,9) and separate the first 9 digits, iterate thru the remaining part of the array joining every 2 elements to create the 2 digit numbers. I was hoping to find a more outright method of doing this.

Comment: I'm given the string, so I won't be able to just create an array that way.

Comment: `"123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930"` Can also give `{12345, 678910, 111213, 141516, 171819, 202122, 232425, 262728, 2930}` From my understanding of the question, you can't figure out what numbers the string represents. Did you mean consecutive numbers?

Comment: From the string above I'd like to get this array as quickly as possible: [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16,17,18,19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27,28,29,30]

Comment: What about this string?
"192837453572"
What's the right answer here?
It could be [1,9,2,8,3,7,4,5,3,5,7,2] or [1928,3,74535,72] or even [192837453572].
I still don't understand how you choose what numbers you're trying to get. As someone else said, if you know the numbers are consecutive and starts with one you can ignore the string and just use the string length.

Comment: Ok so if they're consecutive its doable, but what about if they're not consecutive its not doable correct? Just trying to figure out if this is possible or not.

Comment: @EMK428: It's not so much that it is possible only if the numbers are *consecutive* as much as there must be a *rule* that says where to split the string. All you have shown is the string for 1 to 30, without any indication of what real data you can be expect. In my answer I have proposed that the string be split into the shortest numbers that are monotonically increasing. Something different entirely may be more appropriate but we can't guess if you won't tell us!

Comment: Do you know that the string always contains a `9`?

Comment: You have to make some sort of assumption as there is no delimiting in your input. For example: is the first number always a single-digit one? Are the numbers always consecutive integers? If there’s no pattern to the number of digits in each number then there’s no way you can determine where to split them.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can be sure that every number is greater than its predecessor and greater than zero, and every length of number from a single digit to the maximum is represented at least once, you could write this

```
def split_numbers(str)
  numbers = []
  current = 0
  str.each_char do |ch|
    current = current * 10 + ch.to_i
    if numbers.empty? or current > numbers.last
      numbers << current
      current = 0
    end
  end
  numbers << current if current > 0
  numbers
end

p split_numbers('123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930')
```

**output**

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30]
```

For Anon's example of `192837453572` we get

```
[1, 9, 28, 37, 45, 357, 2]
```

Answer (score 0):

Go through each character of the string, collecting single 'digits', until you find a 9 (set a controlling value and increment it by 1), then continue on collecting two digits, until you find 2 consecutive 9's, and continue on.

This can then be written to handle any sequence of numbers such as your example string.

Comment: We don't know that there will ever be a `9` or a `99`.

Comment: Directly from the OP's question "find the 9,"

Comment: Yeah maybe. But he doesn't seem to be too aware of the implications of variations in the data. I woudn't be surprised if the lack of a `9` hadn't occurred to him! If the string is just a concatenation of consecutive numbers starting a `1` then you can calculate the upper limit from the length of the string.

Comment: It is true, but I would not assume anything except for what he explicitly stated, and that is to find the first 9.  He did not state that the data starts at 1, he only stated "at the first nine". I would probably question him, rather than me, for clarification.  I can only take what it is he gives as specs, not assume anything else.  I did not even assume they were in numerical order, just that there was a '9' to mark the change in the behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
str = "123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930"

result = str[0..8].split('').map {|e| e.to_i }
result += str[9..-1].scan(/../).map {|e| e.to_i }
```

It's essentially the same solution as yours, but slightly cleaner (no need to combine the pairs of digits).  But yeah, if you want a generalizable solution to an arbitrary length string (including more than just 2 digits), that's a different question than what you seem to be asking.

**UPDATE**:

Well, I haven't been able to get this question out of my mind, because it seems like there could be a simple, generalizable solution.  So here's my attempt.  The basic idea is to keep a counter so that you know how many digits the number you want to slice out of the string is.

```
str = "123456789101112131415161718192021222324252627282930"

result = []
i = 1
done = str.length < 1
str_copy = str

while !done do
  result << str_copy.slice!(0..i.to_s.size-1).to_i
  done = true if str_copy.size == 0
  i += 1
end

puts result
```

This generates the desired output, and is generalizable to a string of consecutive positive integers starting with 1.  I'd be very interested to see other people's improvements to this -- it's not super succinct